# How to fix Ubuntu 14.04's File Operations progress dialog for copying from an SSD to a Flash Disk?

Tags: nautilus

At the moment the Dialog quickly progress till the end and stays there for a few minutes and after that shows *0 seconds left* for a minute or two after that before the copy operation is actually finished:

[image: File Operations dialog]

This is pretty much annoying.

Is there a way to fix this??

Comment: What file system on the flash drive ? NTFS ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen This is not about slow transfer rates. The transfer rate makes sense as I am copying to a USB 2 Flash Disk but the progress indicator is not in-sync with the current transfer progress.

Comment: You question states "copying from an SSD to a Flash Disk" and I think the graphical progress bar is out of sync with the actual transfer speed. You can test that from the command line if you wish. `cp Projects-2014-07-01.tar.gz /path/to "STORE N GO". Please update your question with the information I requested. If the flash disk is NTFS you could try reformatting it to ext2 or ext4.

Comment: The target disk is FAT32.

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.